# PolymerTS property decorator error

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, polymer, babeljs

I'm using PolymerTS https://github.com/nippur72/PolymerTS#property decorators with es6 and babel. 
When I'm trying to set property described with `@property` decorator

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'suggestionSelected' of object '#<suggestions-selector>'(…)`

even `readonly` flag is false

some code example, but same error in all similar cases

```
@property({type: Number, value: -1})
suggestionSelected;

onInputKeypress(e) {
    if (keycode(e) === 'down') {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.$.suggestions.selectNext();
    } else if (keycode(e) === 'up') {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.$.suggestions.selectPrevious();
    } else if (keycode(e) === 'enter') {
        this.fire('search', {query: this.$.input.value});
        this.suggestions = [];
        this.suggestionSelected = -1;
    } else {
        this.suggestionSelected = -1; // error here
        this.fetchSuggestions();
    }
}
```

```

Comment: Please show your code. Also note that you don't need Babel if you're already using `tsc`, which is capable of transpiling to ES5.

Comment: @tony19 I'm not using ts, only babel

Comment: You mentioned using PolymerTS decorators, and PolymerTS implies TypeScript. Babel doesn't transpile TypeScript, so you're code won't fully compile even after you resolve the current error.

Comment: @tony19 I'm using compiled es5 version of PolymerTS and all other decorators works perfect

Comment: There are no decorators in ES6.

Comment: @zeroflag omg ok babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: Why go such great lengths to use babel and not just transpile with typescript? :)

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz I'm using Meteor, babel is build-in

Comment: Still, switching to typescript could make your life easier. I googled 'meteor typescript' and there are some possibilities